# Adding a class name when a match is found with jquery,each?

Tags: jquery, arrays, addclass, removeclass, each

I want to add a class to a  element when there a **keyword** is found matched in that 's `href`

html,

```
<ul class="menu-header">
<li><a href="http://localhost/website/#/home/" class="button-header current">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost/website/#/gallery/" class="button-header">GALLERY</a></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost/website/#/people/" class="button-header">PEOPLE</a></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost/website/#/contact/" class="button-header">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

so if the keyword is  "gallery", then "current" should be added to that  element and the "current" class in other elements must be removed.

jquery,

```
var request = "gallery";

// Add the class to the menu.
$(".menu-header li").each(function(){

    var object = $(this); // which is <li>
    var siblings = object.siblings(); // other <li>s

    // Clean all siblings' style.
    siblings.find("a").removeClass('current');
    var array_link = $("a",this).attr("href").split('/');

    if ($.inArray(request, array_link) == 1) $("a.button-header",object).addClass("current");

});
```

I managed to remove "current" class from all elements, but not able to add the "current" class.

Any ideas what I have missed?

Comment: This seems like a Way more complicated way of doing what you are trying to do. What exactly are you trying to do? remove current from all current li's and add current to the one with a given url?

Comment: yes, I want to `remove current from all current li's and add current to the one with a given url` and that url is using keywords such as `gallery`, `home` etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to loop through them all yourself to accomplish this:

```
$(".menu-header li a").removeClass("current").filter("[href*=gallery]").addClass("current");
```

Remove the current class from any `li a` that has it, then add it to the `li a` that has an href that matches `gallery`. Here it is again with a variable:

```
var request = "gallery";
$(".menu-header li a").removeClass("current").filter("[href*=" + reqeust + "]").addClass("current");
```